# Simple fields plugin WordPress show repeatable file field

Tags: plugins

I have install the plugin Simple fields for WordPress, create an repeatable field for file. Upload an amount of images to an portfolio item. Now I will show these images on the page. I use currently the following code:

```
        $file_id = simple_fields_value('image_repeater');
        $image_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src($file_id, "full");
        $image_url = $image_info[0];

        echo "<img src='$image_url' class='imagebox' />";
```

This will show only the first image that I have uploaded.
Now I want to show also the other images, but I don't know how.
Hope somebody can help me out!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For repeatable fields you can use the function simple_fields_values to get an array with all the field values. You can then loop through the array and do whatever you want with the values (in this case the images).

See more info here:

http://simple-fields.com/documentation/api/getting-values/simple_fields_values/

Comment: Yes I have look at your documentation and try a lot of code, but I get only one image to show....
Do you can help me out with the markup. Thank you very much! @Par

Comment: Also I check the values with var_dump and retrieve only the image that is shown. (There are more uploaded) var_dump retrieves: src, height and width. Tried also: `$file_id = simple_fields_value('image_repeater');
foreach ($file_id as $src) {
 $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($file_id, "full");
 $src_url = $src[0];
 echo "<img src='$src_url'/>";
}`
But noting is shown.

Comment: What exactly does `$file_ids = simple_fields_values('image_repeater'); var_dump($file_ids);` return? Also, you don't happen to have another field with the same slug on the same page/post?

Comment: I get it work: `$repeatable_field_values = simple_fields_values("image_repeater");
foreach ($repeatable_field_values as $values) {  
 $image_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src($values, "full");
 $image_url = $image_info[0];
 echo '<br />';
 echo '<img src="'.$image_url.'" class="imagebox" />';

}   

` Thank you for your time. @Pär